# Spring webflux mongodb : save Squillions data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

I have squillions data to save into mongodb. I use **ReactiveMongoRepository.saveAll** only save 256 data rows, how to save it?

this is save part:

```
public Mono<Mailbox> insertMailbox(JsonNode node) {
    this.checkArgs(node);
    Flux<Mailbox> mailboxes = this.getMailboxDoc(node);
    return mailboxTypeRepository
            .findByName(node.get("type").asText("").toUpperCase())
            .flatMap(type -> mailboxRepository.saveAll(this.setMailBoxCategory(node, type, mailboxes))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                    .next())
            .log(LogUtils.getLogger(this.getClass()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
}
```

this getMailboxDoc part:

```
private Flux<Mailbox> getMailboxDoc(JsonNode node) {
        return accountsAdapter.getAllUidSite()
                .parallel()
                .flatMap(accounts -> Mono.just(Mailbox.builder()
                .mid(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .type(TypeEnums.getTypeEnum(node.get("type").asText("")))
                .category(CategoryEnums.getCategoryEnum(node.get("category").asText("")))
                .interlocutor(Lists.asList(node.get("from").asText(), new String[]{node.get("to").asText()}))
                .from(node.get("from").asText())
                .to(accounts.getUidSite())
                .title(node.get("title").asText())
                .content(node.get("content").asText())
                .groupId(this.getGroupId(node.get("groupId")))
                .isDelete(false)
                .isRead(false)
                .site(node.get("site").asText())
                .sendTime(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime())
                .data(mapper.convertValue(node, Map.class))
                .build()))
                .sequential();

}
```

set setMailBoxCategory part:

```
private Flux<Mailbox> setMailBoxCategory(JsonNode node, MailboxType type, Flux<Mailbox> mailboxes) {
    log.debug("setMailBoxCategory :: {}", type.toString());
    Optional<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> target =  type.getCategory()
            .stream()
            .filter(category -> category.get("NAME").equalsIgnoreCase(node.get("category").asText())).findAny();
    if (target.isPresent()) {
        return mailboxes.parallel()
                .map(mailbox -> {
                    mailbox.setCategoryId(target.get().get("ID"));
                    return mailbox;
                })
                .sequential();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgException("");
    }
}
```

accountsRepository.getAllUidSite() is use r2dbc to get info.